# Two's Complement: Addition Overflow?

Tags: binary, twos-complement

I am trying to add 24 to 10 in 2's complement. I found 24 in 2's complement to be: 011000 and 10 in 2's complement to be 001010. When I add the two together I get: 100010. The result is a negative number. Is this an example of overflow? Is it not possible to add 24 to 10 in 2's complement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have 6 bits, then yes, it is an overflow.  The reason is that 6-bit 2's complement can only store numbers `-32..31` and your desired result, `34`, is outside that range.

If you had, say, 8 bits instead, your result would be `00100010`, which would not be a negative number, or an overflow.

Adding two positive numbers and coming up with a negative result, or two negative numbers and coming up with a non-negative result, is a definitive indicator of signed 2's complement overflow.